# How to write a report with multiple filters for the same field in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The below report is currently written using linq to entities to get the data and building an html table in code. I'd like to rewrite it using SSRS and need some advice.

All of the data is in the same table. There will also be date range parameters.

Here is the basic template for the report that is needed.

```
Categories    0-30     31-60      61-90       >90
Category1     0*         0          0          0
Category2     0          0          0          0
Category3     0          0          0          0
Category4     0          0          0          0
Category5     0          0          0          0
```

As an example, to get the first value (*) the select statement would look something like

```
SELECT
  SUM(ItemCount) As Sum_ItemCount
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  TotalLength < 30
  AND Date >= @Date
  AND Date <= @Date2
  AND Category == 'Category1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SSRS using a Matrix object (similar to an Excel PivotTable) - for further details, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28SQL.100%29.aspx

EDIT - suggested sample query:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN TotalLength <= 30 THEN '0-30'
       WHEN TotalLength > 30 AND TotalLength <= 60 THEN '31-60'
       WHEN TotalLength > 60 AND TotalLength <= 90 THEN '61-90'
       ELSE '>90'
  END AS LengthBand,
  Category,
  SUM(ItemCount) As Sum_ItemCount
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  Date >= @Date
  AND Date <= @Date2
```

Comment: This is a good start. For their columns they had field values. I need custom column headers. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I suggest doing it in SQL - I have added a sample query, above. (It is also possible to do this using a conditional expression in the Matrix Properties Groups Columns definition, but grouping in the query will reduce the quantity of data being passed to the report.)

Comment: Thanks! That gets me started.